# Rails RecordNotFound not routing to 404 page, whereas routing error does

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In our existing Rails 5 application, I recently noticed that a RecordNotFound error results in a simple "Resource not found" body text along with the 404 status code. For some reason Rails does not route to the 404.html page in the public directory.

On the other hand, Rails **does** render that 404.html page when a routing error occurs.

What could be causing this difference and how do I get the RecordNotFound to also render the 404.html?

Comment: Normally they should be handled the same way., my bet is there a rescue_from in your application controller that is handling the record not found exception differently.

Comment: OMG... it was actually hard to overlook this `rescue_from` in the `application_controller` and yet I did. Thank you for pointing out that it had to be something this blatantly obvious.